# Delay rendering JSX in React

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a super hero comparison and I want each stat to render 500ms after the previous. `window.setTimeout` is not helping me.

here is my code inside my React functional component:

```js
function showStatsA() {
        return (
            <div ref={statsA} className="stats-hidden">
                <p>Power Stats</p>
                {renderCombatA()}
            </div>
        );
    }

function renderCombatA() {
        window.setTimeout(() => {
            return (
                <p>
                    Combat: {fighterA[3].combat}
                    test
                </p>
            );
        }, 500);
    }

return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <SearchDiv>
                <div className="search-a" ref={cardA}>
                    {renderSearchA()}
                    {showFighterA()}
                    {showStatsA()}
                    <div id="loadA" className="hidden">
                        <Loading />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="vs">
                    <button
                        ref={readyBtn}
                        className={ready ? 'begin-button' : 'hidden'}
                        onClick={beginBattle}>
                        Click to Begin Battle
                    </button>
                    <button ref={resetBtn} className="reset-button" onClick={reset}>
                        Reset Fighters
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div className="search-b" ref={cardB}>
                    {renderSearchB()}
                    {showFighterB()}
                    {showStatsB()}

                    <div id="loadB" className="hidden">
                        <Loading />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </SearchDiv>
        </React.Fragment>
    );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to manage state for that, using `useEffect` will make your code more simple.

```
const toggle = p => !p;

const App = () => {
  const [visibleA, setVisibleA] = useState(false);
  const [visibleB, setVisibleB] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setVisibleA(toggle);
    }, 1000);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (visibleA) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        setVisibleB(toggle);
      }, 1000);
    }
  }, [visibleA]);

  return (
    <>
      {visibleA && `A`}
      {visibleB && `B`}
    </>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit upbeat-flower-8y4ki]